# Set Publisher in Word Options Add-Ins Dialog

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, ms-office, vsto, office-2010

I have made an addin for Microsoft Word 2010 Beta using Visual Studio 2010 RTM.  When I look at "View and manage Microsoft Office Add-ins" the publisher shows up as None.

Would code signing with a Software Publisher Certificate fill in the Publisher field?

The ClickOnce manifest is signed with a Code Signing certificate.

Would signing the assembly with a strong name key file fill in the Publisher field?

Is there a method using codesign.exe that would fill in the Publisher field?

Note: Using signtool.exe to sign the addin dll with the certificate results in the publisher showing as None in Word.

Comment: Were you able to do this with Word 2007 and VS 2008? Or is this the first time you've created a VSTO Add-in?

Comment: I haven't tried this with Word 2007 and VS 2008.  This is my first VSTO addin.

I have looked at using MAGE on the manifest and vsto files and signing those.  Setting the Publisher in the manifest conficted with Click-Once and Word 2010 would not load the addin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be modifying the targets file to set details like Publisher. This solution, albeit for VSTO 2008, should still be applicable to 2010: http://blogs.msdn.com/vsto/archive/2008/06/11/specify-a-product-name-publisher-name-and-other-properties-for-vsto-solutions-saurabh-bhatia.aspx

Comment: This looks like it has potential. I will try it out.

Comment: The comments to the linked blog article indicate that it is not possible to set the publisher in the office addins dialog for a vsto addin and the the publisher will always appear as none.  It is not the answer I was hoping for but is an indication that what I was trying to do is not possible.