# Visual Studio: Managed To Sign Assembly, ClickOnce manifests but Publisher is missing

Tags: visual-studio, code-signing

I was under the impression that when I sign both the ClickOnce manifests and the assembly in VisualStudio that I would see the publisher name when starting the exe and it requests permissions, but after building the project the Publisher is still missing

What am I missing here? Visual Studio does not complain about my cert and it looks like it imported it correctly showing the correct info

- Issued To
- Issued By COMODO
- Intended Purpose .. etc

Edit: Managed to find this, this may already help [Unknown Publisher still appears on correctly code-signed VSTO addin built with VS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514576/unknown-publisher-still-appears-on-correctly-code-signed-vsto-addin-built-with-v)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer to my problem is mageUI.exe or mage.exe

mageUI.exe allows to add a default signing cert to manually sign the manifest
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhctdw55(v=vs.110).aspx

I was under the impression that VisualStudio would automatically do this, but its either not working for me or it was not intended to work this way