# Publisher name of VSTO add-in in outlook add-in list

Tags: outlook, vsto, add-in

I am facing the issue that my VSTO add-in is not displaying the publisher name in Outlook's add-in dialog. It is showing as `<None>`. I am using VS2013 for development. I tried by signing it but did not work. Can anybody please give some specific steps to do it?

Comment: Could this earlier post solve your issue?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514576/unknown-publisher-still-appears-on-correctly-code-signed-vsto-addin-built-with-v

Comment: That question is about correctly showing the publisher when using the ClickOnce installer. It is kind of related but doesn't solve the problem discussed here.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately showing the publisher name is not possible for VSTO Add-ins. Even if you sign

- all your ClickOnce files with your Authenticode certificate
- your assembly

  - [With signtool (Authenticode)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35512623/1200847)
  - Strong Name with CA-signed certificate

and set all possible publisher/company/...-fields for your assembly and the ClickOnce-manifest, the publisher will not show up in the Add-in dialog. This is due to how VSTO security works as [commented by this VSTO team member](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsto/2009/10/19/visual-studio-2010-specify-advanced-publishing-options-saurabh-bhatia/#comment-7333).

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign the add-in with your own digital signature (not a strong name signature). Did you purchase a certificate from a trusted vendor?

See [Introduction to Code Signing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537361%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information in MSDN.

Comment: I have code signing certificate, even after signing it from the certificate it is not showing

Comment: What file did you sign with a digital signature? An add-in loader?

Comment: i have signed assembly and dll

Comment: You need to sign the add-in loader instead.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev By add-in loader, you mean the .vsto file?